# How to alter a column in HANA DB to be incremented, after that table was already created?

Tags: database, schema, auto-increment, ddl, hana

I want to have a table with this properties:

```
CREATE TABLE status
(
    identificationnumber BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    desc varchar(10)
);
```

Suddenly the production table was already created and has a enormous amount of data. Schema that is already in use:

```
CREATE TABLE status
(
    identificationnumber BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    desc varchar(10)
);
```

Is it possible to update the schema with an autoincrement?

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is possible, but may depend on the size of data. You can check it by yourself at TEST/QAS system and then apply the change to production.
Here's the code I used:

```
/*Create example table*/
create column table tst_tab (
  x int
);
/*Fill it with some data*/
insert into tst_tab
select 1 from dummy union all
select 2 from dummy union all
select 3 from dummy
;
/*Add identity column*/
alter table tst_tab
add(id int generated by default as identity);
/*Statement 'alter table tst_tab add(id int generated by default as identity)' 
successfully executed in 14 ms 281 µs*/
/*Check results*/
select * from tst_tab;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: So this relies on creating a new Table, right? This would be a Problem in the production environment. Is there a possibility to do the same without service downtime?

Comment: @SGTechEdge I didn't create a "temporary" table in my example. Just added the column to existing table (which I created in the very beginning of my script).

Comment: AH true, sory for the mistake. The table is already created without Identity. I am serching for a way to create an identity on it.

Comment: @SGTechEdge I've updated my answer with comments. In the example I've tested the scenario you described (add autogenerated ID column to some table), so I don't understand what's wrong in it.